# Why does the source code of a website vary when visited from different browsers?

Tags: javascript, css, html, class

Look at the source code of bartzmall.pk from different browsers and you will see different classes added to the html tag for each browser.

From firefox

```
<html class="firefox firefox53 otherClasses">
```

From chrome

```
<html class="webkit chrome chrome58 otherClasses">
```

From IE

```
<html class="ie ie11 otherClasses">
```

And from opera

```
<html class="webkit opera opera45 otherClasses">
```

The class "otherClasses" refer to about 14 other classes that are common for all browsers.

How is this website able to change its source code when visited from different browsers? What purpose do these special classes that vary by browser serve?

P.S As a side question, what is the sense/wisdom/reason behind adding so many classes to the html tag?

Comment: The server can detect the user-agent.

Comment: They add so many html classes to help identify the browser type, to maintain the same view on every browser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a JS plugin named "modrnizer" (google it) which detects your browser type and capabilities and inserts according classes into your HTML tags, so you can setup CSS rules that respond to the particular differences between browsers using those classes .

The modrnizer website itself seems to be broken at the moment, but here is an article that describes how it works: http://html5doctor.com/using-modernizr-to-detect-html5-features-and-provide-fallbacks/

Comment: I have used modernizr but all that detection occurs in if statements and no js plugin can change the source code of a website it can change based on browser that way that code is read and its functionality but the source code is permanent and static

Comment: The way I see it your answer is either incomplete or wrong

Comment: @AsifAli JS can add classes to HTML tags, so if you can detect browsers, you can insert according classes into the HTML code. I added a link to an article about it.

Comment: the only way i see that possible is that they have seperate webpages for different websites, with different code for different browsers. they use modernizr to detect which browser and then REDIRECT to the webpage made for that browser because the code"think of it as a txt file" is permanent and absolute it does not change the way it is used changes. Am i correct? can anyone plz help this is driving me crazy. @Johannes read the article did not help me understand.

Comment: The adding of those classes happens on page load: First the script detects which browser there is and what it's capable of. Then it adds according classes to the HTML tags (mainly the HTML tag, I think), using functions like "addClass".  All that happens on page load. It's not in the HTML code initially, but gets written in there immediately when a page is loaded. Now CSS rules for those classes can react to the situation: E.g., if HTML now contains "noflex", a `html.noflex div.mydiv` selector can provide an appropriate setting for the element `.mydiv` which normally uses `flex`. And so on...

Comment: ok now i get it thanks and sorry for the trouble didn't know this was possible

Comment: checking browser type is always bad idea, as agent sniffing.

Comment: @user3573535 The question is about certain classes in the HTML tag. I explained where such classes can come from and the way this works. THere's absolutely no reason to downvote that answer  (except that you apparently got upset by a comment to a question of yours asking you to post code where you only posted images, which is nothing but immature behaviour)

Comment: @Johannes,i dont agree.

Comment: @user3573535 What do you not agree about?

Comment: @Johannes about modernizer.

Comment: @user3573535 I didn't even say it's good or bad - the question was only about where these classes come from, and I explained it.

Comment: @Johannes this are hacks, modernizer may be not developed in future and i don't agree with you , as for me this is similar to agent sniffing, co can code something, but new devices will appear, and you will have to update your code. for me best to keep standards.

Comment: @user3573535 You don't really understand what I am saying, do you?